# Would this Falstad simulation of a 50 kV flyback system work in real life?

Tags: high-voltage, voltage-multiplier

I am trying to make a 10 kV 10 kHz generator by modifying this circuit:

[image: the original flyback circuit]

I am thinking of connecting 220 V DC at the output of the MOSFET and using a transformer with 1:50 ratio:

[image: something like this]

[Falstad simulation.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3EZgEwA4AslkFZ1gGz6oDsxe+IG4AzCNpHQKYC0YYAUAdiMscj9grUqOCmEjUGYaMjbpk+SOnzYCkAJzpiLNuwBmIYtn7VkDVHBCmGmcAxiRU7AG4h1FfHzdClUP7ZQ-e2hsdgB3b3BAs1Qo-khwq2oxQOpknmR0KET3Hi9ctnjEmLi8-kLsgGMrYwys9FM6oNglYigW8V5iMFR1TUJjdD72hESG-mRMkHGQfCmEiJLPE19l7IAnaca5+u2vKXgFnkdZ-I999mq0inIk8-jwFljiaBVifE11R3VVVDQRyAcCLXU78GZrI68ExmaboWLWbIRbDqaEMZETC5IlFWGHoqxERF0bFQ2ZTElHPHJWI7fGxBIAF1JWRJKgo5PAIFY0j62Go6ms2G6kHesWYMEkjlQgnkGlIoja4gYAGcAA4AS0qLAAJow9ABDACuABt6exGTSqbNBLS-KxwDI5AolCo1JptFzOeK4KgpfgZeo5YIFZZVRrtbrDSbEqyeD6rUIYUcYwjk7Uk9aEUZUYSU14QRDEpIsmsi9MCITcFkKjGKumUvwY6JCcmqDGCxE215K6DsgAVSgWcDoKtYKuBGx0BhilqCRyC4dgPr4ReNZgvZEi9yKehmWQ6NowPrqdgAcxxDBLMKIdJ4havedWmLow9KINr7E2uVLuXZQNh8NxbEEUhLwKjfcdilA6IvDQOlC3SSYsmoWpEKqZ8kKobsIR4J5DBkKVkGEP4yFHAkHEBRI8RKbsSgpF81CJcpFGyLVGPAZiqJOcoADlMCUD90PYtEX1ojI4AE7sKkk5ibGIcSkRfNZwSfbtkP4GiTjojD6ksYQsi0qxMJfNSK2M2o+JqIoFKrDjAgYik7NsiY4wc5zYgs2DshVOwAjspQpGMoJEk6Mdyn80ojhCocRwCF8Ek2H0pECRLwH+A5xNYlKwBfLL-n4HV9WNU1XFQctF34Ur6yCaYGEmexmlCCJKvAbFmtLI42t8CwGHaxJuruAcevSDrBxBLK4r68tS2a9tKHLNZOyKBKyuSwdayHdgAHs6FoRBY35WJxHUH1oC3SZiGoMAswBQE-A4IA)

- Would this circuit actually work in real life conditions?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

The output will go into a Cockcroft Walton multiplier and output 50 kV which will then be used to power an ionic thruster, so the required current output is very small (1-2 mA).

Comment: Welcome! Please design your transformer and add calculated primary and secondary resistance, inductance and leakage inductance to your simulation and re-run it.

Comment: No, that circuit would not work.

Comment: Okay, can you point me in a direction so I can accomplish 10kv at 10Khz please.

Comment: The diode parallel to the transformer will catch all the flyback energy you want to produce. You need an R/C snubber element at this place. It is not so easy to find a MOSFET that withstands the high voltage peak > 2 kV. Better use a lower DC supply voltage which would work with a 1 kV MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It is an isolation transformer i don't understand why the mosfet would see high voltage